# Why is there not a basic SortedList<T>?

Tags: c#, .net, data-structures, generics

As far as I know, there is no way to get a `List<T>` with the capacity to sort itself. If I add a element, I want the data-structure to insert it in the right position (based on the associated `IComparer<T>`). I am looking for something with the same logic than `SortedSet<T>`.

I am aware of `System.Collections.Generic.SortedList<TKey, TValue>` but it is more a kind of `Dictionary`.

I don't really need one (it is not very difficult to implement). I just wonder whether a such data-structure exists and if not, why?

source:

- [`List<T>` OrderBy Alphabetical Order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188141/list-orderby-alphabetical-order)
- [Is there a list that is sorted automatically in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721889/is-there-a-list-that-is-sorted-automatically-in-net)
- [`SortedList` Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist.aspx)
- [`SortedList<TKey, TValue>` Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [`SortedSet<T>` Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412070%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Probably because `List<T>` already contains two `Sort` methods and a `BinarySearch` method, effectively making it already a `SortedList<T>`

Comment: @Robert but with O(n) insertion cost.

Comment: What is the use case of `SortedList`?

Comment: ... for some reason it *does* exist ([docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319(v=vs.110).aspx)), though as an IDictonary rather than an IList. This confuses me. Especially since the IList Add method ([docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist.add(v=vs.110).aspx)) doesn't have anything about appending to the end of the list (compare [Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add-E-)). Having the List be defined as 'append' makes a SortedList a violation of the contract (which isn't the case in C# and thus my 'why not?')

Comment: @CodesInChaos: In a `List<T>?` I doubt it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Hmm? If you want to add an item while keeping the list sorted, you need to move half the list on average.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: You don't have to take that cost until you actually sort the array.  Sorting != insertion.

Comment: What is wrong with SortedSet?

Comment: @Frisbee Everything is fine with SortedSet. It is just a set not a list.

Comment: What would be the difference between a SortedSet and a SortedList?

Comment: @Frisbee The main difference is in a set each element is unique. It is not the case in a list.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It would break the [`IList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6(v=vs.110).aspx) interface.

You retrieve elements out of a list by index, if the indices for the elements keep changing this is useless, also Insert would be useless.

**Item[Int32] - Gets or sets the element at the specified index.**

**Insert(Int32, T) - Inserts an item to the `IList<T>` at the specified index.**

So the reason there is no `SortedList<T>` implementation is because other ADTs can handle the functionality in a more rational and efficient manner.

Comment: It could implement ICollection and IReadOnly List instead